# Selecting df rows common with series

Tags: python, pandas

```
Datetime
2015-01-08 17:30:00     4942
2015-01-08 18:00:00     5983
2015-01-08 18:30:00     6732
Length: 3, dtype: int64
```

I have next `df`:

```
          A             Datetime        B   
4166    Thu  2015-01-08 17:30:00        8             
4942    Sat  2015-01-08 17:30:00        5             
5983    Tue  2015-01-08 18:00:00        1             
4216    Thu  2015-01-08 18:00:00        3             
4232    Mon  2015-01-08 18:30:00        3             
6732    Mon  2015-01-08 18:30:00        4
```

I want to get a new df1, selecting rows in df common with above series.

df1 should be:

```
          A             Datetime        B          
4942    Sat  2015-01-08 17:30:00        5             
5983    Tue  2015-01-08 18:00:00        1                      
6732    Mon  2015-01-08 18:30:00        4
```

Answer (score 1):

It is `isin`

```
df=df.reset_index()
s=s.reset_index()

df.loc[df[['index','Datetime']].astype(str).sum(1).isin(s.astype(str).sum(1)),:]
```